How can I get ufw working on a computer sitting behind a mobile hotspot?
I'm running Pop!_OS 22.04 on a computer connected to the internet via a Franklin JEXtream RG2100 5G Mobile Hotspot on the T-Mobile network. My ufw config that works behind a traditional cable modem does not work behind this mobile Hotspot.
My ufw rules allow 443 traffic out to anywhere and allow all traffic to and from the Hotspot. DNS works on the computer behind the mobile Hotspot with ufw enabled.
EXPECTED: I can hit any website.
ACTUAL:
With these rules and ufw enabled, I cannot hit any website. When I try to hit any website that supports https, I get a timeout error message from the browser saying, "You are seeing this error because this site does not support https". My system log does not show ufw blocking any traffic to or from anywhere when trying to hit websites with ufw enabled behind the Hotspot. When I disable ufw, I can hit any website.
